# c++ string to ipAddress windows/unix system

Tags: c++, windows, string, unix, ip-address

can i convert string to ip address in c + + on multiple platforms
Windows (various versions) and Unix systems?

Comment: What excatly do you need ... you have to convert a string to astring formatted in this way xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want. What is this string? A host name or an IP address, or ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `inet_addr()` function to convert an IP address represented as a string into the form that can be used with other socket functions.

Here's an example use (taken from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r9.cbcpx01/oana.htm)):

```
int rc;
int s;
struct sockaddr_in myname;

/* clear the structure to be sure that the sin_zero field is clear */
memset(&myname, 0, sizeof(myname));
myname.sin_family = AF_INET;
myname.sin_addr = inet_addr("129.5.24.1");
/* specific interface */
myname.sin_port = htons(1024);
```

Comment: I have to write code that works for both Windows and UNIX systems.
This can not know before. How to change this code?

Comment: What must i is include in order to use this code on both Windows and Unix systems?

Comment: @GgSalent: The includes differ for Windows and *NIX. On Windows its likely to be `<winsock2.h>` and on *NIX `<sys/socket.h>`. You can still provide a "portable" code using preprocessor conditions like: `#ifdef __WIN32__`.

Comment: I did this but I have a lot of mistakes ..
I have included everything? I use Windows XP at this time 

#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#endif

Comment: From memory, I think you need to include `winsock2.h` before `windows.h`. (Also I think `winsock2.h` and `winsock.h` are incompatible, so watch out for that too! - it's a real pain the first time you try this stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hostname or FQDN and you need a DNS query or internal host list query to translate it to an IP Address, then you need to use `gethostbyname`.